# Is there an Eventhub Explorer debugging tool?

Tags: azure-eventhub

I have a EventHub receiver running in a WebJob.

We are currently with the BASIC tier, so we are limited to 1 Consumer Group.

I'm looking for a debugging tool that would allow me to consult the EventHub stream without affecting the running WebJob.

I tried the [Azure Service Bus Explorer](https://github.com/paolosalvatori/ServiceBusExplorer), but it gives this exception:

```
Exception: A receiver with a higher epoch '14' already exists. A new receiver with epoch 0 cannot be created. 
Make sure you are creating receiver with increasing epoch value to ensure connectivity, or ensure all old epoch receivers are closed or disconnected.
```

Using a different Consumer Group solve this issue, but as I said, I would like to stay with BASIC tier if possible.